# Why spring boot didn't save my sessions and cookies between requests?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, session, spring-rest

Spring boot doesn't save sessions between requests. I have to methods: /login and another one is /getInfo. They're placed in different controllers. DB for sessions is MongoDB and I can see through Mongo Compass that there are adding new sessions documents. So, I'm making post request to /login, where session are creating and after that I'm making request to /getInfo where I want to take data from session and I get [This is an screen of session and the data in each sessions(including sessions id)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WoBO.png). As result I have two different sessions

This is how the session sets:

```
session.setAttribute("username", resp.get("username"));
```

This is how data are getting from session:

```
session.getAttribute("username")
```

[Image of request data #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2j5H.png)

[Image of request data #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnlXm.png)

Comment: From the screenshot, I don't see a cookie with a JSESSIONID being sent in the request headers. Because there isn't a session ID being passed in, a new session is created each time.  The response headers would then contain a Set-Cookie header with the created session - JSESSIONID. It is expected for this to be passed back for the server to lookup the corresponding session in subsequent requests.

Comment: Can you add more details like how the session object is being injected in your code, which could help to identify the issue?

Comment: [This is GitHub repository with part of code](https://github.com/Abuzik/stackIssue)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will use @RestController with sessions add two rows into your controller:

```java
    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;
```